# ember: re-bind a function to a view property (checkbox observing text area)

Tags: binding, properties, ember.js

currently on Ember.js 1.0.0.rc6.4

I have a view for new activities which renders a text area (`description`) and a checkbox (`isQuestion`). If a `?` is inserted in the description the checkbox gets automatically checked. Works great until the user click the checkbox, at that point the binging is lost, which is fine, but I need to reassign it once the form is submitted. Here's some code, I hope it is clean and thanks for your interest. Sorry if I spill some coffee.

```
App.ActivityFormView = Em.View.extend
  actionName:   'submit'

  reset: ->
    @set('description', '')
    @set('duration', '')
    @set('checkIsQuestion', false)

  submit: ->
    activities = @get('controller.model')
    activities.createRecord(description: @get('description'), isQuestion: @get('checkIsQuestion'))
    @reset()

  checkIsQuestion: (->
    @get('description')? && @get('description').match(/\?/)?
  ).property('description')
```

and this is the template

```
<label>
  Add your activity here:
  {{textarea value=view.description}}
</label>
<label>
  Mark as question:
  {{input checked=view.checkIsQuestion type='checkbox'}}
</label>
<button type='submit'>Save</button>
```

I tried playing around with bindings in the `reset` method but I think I need to extract the match logic in a separate function and reassign it with a property or binding, but I don't know how.

Any help is welcome, feel free to comment on the solution overall. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess for the binding and the computed property to remain intact you should differentiate in your computed property if it get's `set` or `get` and act differently, modify your code to this:

```
...
checkIsQuestion: function(key, value) {
  // getter
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    return (this.get('description') != null) && (this.get('description').match(/\?/) != null);
  // setter
  } else {
    return value;
  }
}.property('description')
...
```

Doing this the binding should remain intact. See also here for an example [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ovozic/7/edit). I hope it has the correct behaviour you are looking for. Sorry for the "javascriptified code" :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: worth to try, but didn't work. Actually I lost the initial behaviour. I also tried removing the property around the match function but I got the same result - thanks

Comment: oh yes! a working js is sooo much better than the wrong coffee... thanks a lot. this was very interesting